# Should I replace the AC charger as well when buying a new battery?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

My notebook is already 4 years old, and it's battery basically died from one day to another (one day it could support the notebook for an hour, the next day I could get at most 2-3 minutes out of it). Of course I'm looking into replacing the batteries, but I have a strange worrying feeling that it was my AC adaptor that killed the batteries, as it's also quite old already.

The computer works perfectly fine when plugged in via the AC adapter, so I'm not sure whether I should also buy a new adapter as well with the new battery, or whether my worries are unfounded and getting a new adapter would just be a waste of money?

Comment: If the original battery was 4 years old, it probably died of natural causes.  Buy a replacement battery and see if it charges properly with your existing charger.  The only reason to replace the charger would be if it's not working, which you can easily test.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason why you are suspicious of the AC adapter? If it works fine when the computer is plugged in I see no reason why you would want to change it.